# Can Chrome devtools track element with focus?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm testing my HTML on accessibility. While navigating the HTML with the TAB key, the focus ring sometimes disappears because the element that has focus is hidden. At that point i can't tell which DOM element has focus.
Is there a way i can track in Chrome DEVtools which element has focus while TABbing through the page?

Comment: As of Chrome 70, Live Expressions provide an easy way to do this. See the [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543066/1669860) in my answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Update

[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/accessibility/focus)

As of Chrome 70, which released in August 2018, [Live Expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch) provide an easier way to track which element has focus.

1. Open the Console.
2. Click **Create Live Expression** [image: Create Live Expression].

   [image: Live Expression UI]
3. Type `document.activeElement`.
4. Click outside of the Live Expression UI to save.

As of Chrome 71, which was released in October 2018, when you hover over a Live Expression result that evaluates to a node (as is the case with `document.activeElement`), DevTools highlights the node in the viewport.

[image: Hovering over the Live Expression result]

## Original Answer

Thanks for posting. Seems like a common and useful workflow, yet I've never thought about it.

1. While focused on the hidden element, evaluate `document.activeElement` in the Console.

   [image: Running document.activeElement in the Console.]
2. Right-click > **Reveal in Elements panel**.

   [image: Hovering over "Reveal in Elements panel".]

The **DOM Tree** is highlighting the hidden element.

[image: The hidden element is highlighted in the Elements panel.]

Here is the [demo](https://a11yfocus.glitch.me/), if you'd like to try it yourself.

P.S. [I tweeted out this workflow from the DevTools account](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/1022515019379077120).

Comment: It can also be nice to add `document.activeElement` to "Live Expression" [feature](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch)

Comment: @MariuszPawelski thanks for the ping. I updated my answer to include the Live Expression workflow.